# How to set $location.path and $location.search at the same time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angular ngRouter. I need to change the url path along with search parameters. I know about $location.path and $location.search, but is there a function that sets them both?

Comment: what exactly you want to do, could you elaborate more on it?

Comment: I have a path string, and query parameters object (key/value pairs). I want to build url from both and set the new url in one step. (since I doubt it is recommended to call $location.path and $location.search sequentially, if even possible, since it would introduce additional intermediate state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$location.url()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) to change path, search, and hash all at once.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but what is the recommended way to pass query (search) parameters to $location.url, besides manual string concatenation. I have these parameters in object (key/val pairs).